# Understanding Scene Graphs and Graph Edges

Tags: c++, graph, hierarchy, scenegraph

So I'm trying to getting to grips with using Scene graphs and nodes in my code (game coding in C++) and I think I understand the basics of them and how they are used (and I can definitely see the benefits), but I'm coming across the term "*Graph Edge*" and I can't find any reading material explaining exactly what they are and how they fit in with Scene Graphs/trees/nodes in object hierarchy structures.

If anyone knows of any good material or has their own answer on what graph edges are and how they fit in (in use and implementation) that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a graph, edges connect vertices. This is just by definition of what a graph is in that context, look up a basic lecture on graph theory in the context of computer science.

Note that there are other definitions for a graph, and also this has nothing to do with graphic, even though you will render the scene to a picture probably.